# how to use keywords in searchengine

Tags: php, html, loops, mysqli, search-engine

hello i`m sitting here and thinking about the following issue:

i have a autosuggestion search engine that runs through a table like:

```
zipcode    city       sum

12345      town       5
```

i do realize the search by using javascript that runs through a loop on each letter that will be typed in. up to that point i only can look for one keyword that can be city name or zipcode for example.

now i would like to combine these both so that i do not limit an user anymore to one of these both and even when entering city and zipcode it will be found.

therefor i would like to seperate each keyword by using:

```
preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
```

this is the problem at the moment. using this means, every keyword will be inserted in an array. how it works:

in the html i have an input field. below that i have an unordered list div. in that div javascript is automatically adding the results from my search.php file. that looks like:

```
include('../scripts/db_connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {

$search_term = $db->real_escape_string(htmlentities(trim($_POST['search_term'])));

$search_term_query = "SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE `b` LIKE '$search_term%'";

if ($result_query = $db->query($search_term_query)) {

    while ($row = $result_query->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<li>', 
          $row["a"], 
          ' ', 
          $row["b"],  
          ' ',
          '( ',
          $row["c"],
          ' )', 
          ' </li>';
    }

}

}
```

and my javascript is only handling one keyword:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.searchfield').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post('ajax/search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);

            $('.result li').click(function() {
                var result_value = $(this).text();
                $('.searchfield').attr('value', result_value);
                $('.result').html('');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

so at the moment i dont know how to solve that. if there is someone who could help me out i really would appreciate. thanks.

Comment: You might want to use simply `explode` instead of `preg_split`: http://micro-optimization.com/explode-vs-preg_split

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the value as it is and send the whole string to your php file through a post call.
In your search.php you can try something like this:

```
function split_search_term($val) {
    $val = explode(" ", $val);
    $search_term_query = "SELECT * FROM `a` WHERE ";
    foreach($val as $val_row) {
        $search_term_query .= "(`zipcode` LIKE '" . $search_term . "%' OR `city`  LIKE '" . $search_term . "%') OR ";
    }
    if(count($val) > 0) {
        // The IF statement is used to make sure that the foreach loop has been fired at least once,
        // or else it would just chop off the 'WHERE ' part and you'll get something like:
        // "SELECT * FROM `a` WH" and this will give you an error
        $search_term_query = substr($search_term_query, 0, -4); // To cut off the last remaining ' OR ' in the query
    } else {
        $search_term_query .= "0"; // To finish the query so it doesn't return anything we don't want
    }

    return $search_term_query;
}
```

From here you can go ahead and fetch the result. I hope it works.